# How do I know when I've 100%'d the game?

Tags: the-witness

I've been reading forums and I've seen multiple quotes that give different numbers for how many puzzles there are total, and this gets muddied a bit by the question of what actually counts as a puzzle.

It's really unclear to me how a person would know when they've completed/found everything the game has to offer in terms of puzzles and collectibles like audio/video recordings.

Is there an official count on the number of puzzles in the game in terms of what gets reported when you look at your save file? Are there other puzzles that aren't accounted for in the save file statistics? How many audio and visual recordings are there?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

@Devon Parsons answered quite correctly, but to make the answer more complete:

[image]

1. The **pond** is a very clever **map** of the whole island. All parts of the lake facе to the corresponding areas. The lake's water corresponds to island's shore; and the wet shore (rocks) near the lake correspond to island's water in-between shore (where tree houses and shipwreck is located); actually you can see the shipwreck in the lake as a piece of metal; also you can see a woman statue, which correspond to the statue on the mountain.
2. 11 big **lanterns** are the **lasers**. *If a lantern lit - the laser is activated.*
3. 6 **fountains** are the **obelisks**. *If a fountain is high in the air - all puzzles on the obelisk have been solved.*
4. The **flowers** are the **audio-logs**. White flowers are the usual ones, yellow - are the golden, which you can find underground when open the mountain secret door. *If a flower blossoms - the log were found and activated.*
5. 7 **clams** are the **vaults** with sheet of paper inside. *If a clam is open - the vault was open.*
6. Finally and most importantly for the completion: 14 triangular **leaves** are the **small 3x3 puzzles scattered** around the whole island. *If a leaf is sunken and hardly visible - the puzzle was solved.*
7. Unfortunately, the lake doesn't label "usual" puzzles, to be sure that you've done them all you need to **go to menu/saved games and check the first number to be 523** (the second and third correspond to the puzzles on the obelisks and number of the obelisks, they must be +135 +6, but you can check all of them with the lake and the obelisks themselves). Some of those "usual" puzzles are tricky to find, but most of them you won't be able to avoid when you will hunt for the listed above lake-things, the rest easy-to-miss-puzzles are the ones, which allows to use various shortcuts and shortcuts (these shortcuts should be relatively obvious). Once you've done all of these you should have 523 puzzles count, but if you stack you can use this [manual](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witness/Easy_to_Miss_Puzzles), for example.

Comment: According to [Jonathan Blow's post](http://the-witness.net/news/2015/01/progress/), there are around 677 puzzles in the game.

Answer (score 21):

Your save file will be labelled with 523, +135, +6.

The lake next to the city is an indicator of your progress in the game. The lake itself is shaped like the island, and acts like a map. After completing every possible action in the game, all the lanterns will be lit (each one corresponding to a laser, except for the flickering one held by the statue, which is always lit); all the white and yellow flowers will blossom (I believe they correspond to the audio logs); the 6 fountains will spray high into the air (each one corresponds to an obelisk) and the clams underwater will be open (each one corresponds to a video log in the theatre below the windmill, except for one clam which corresponds with the secret ending).

Comment: It looks like the clams are the windmill videos, are the orange leaves and the orange-triangle puzzles.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Not quite, the clams are those boxes on the pedestals/sheets of paper (there's 7 clams, but only 6 videos).

Comment: Also the statement about the statue isn't quite correct as well. It will sink (and the lantern will extinguish) when you unlock the final challenge area. And the colour of the flowers is also significant (they do both correspond to audio logs, but the orange ones are specifically for the audio logs found in said challenge area).

Comment: Here is the [video](https://youtu.be/m89WOJIT--k?list=PL5dr1EHvfwpNYbS_yqCZg30lEnpiEF6O2&t=2190) demonstrating _+523+135+6_ completion.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to go to the lake and see if the lamp has went out.

In my play, I solved everything except one last puzzle (so 522 +135 +6) and one last audio log (so one flower not blooming).

I first sought out the last puzzle and completed it, and went back to the lake and saw the lamp still flickering. Then I traced down the last audio log and played it for once. After returning to the lake, I found the lamp completely went out. The statue underneath it also changed to a new pose.

[image]

Therefore I conclude that the lamp is an indicator of 100% completion. It's arguably easier to check out than looking in the pause menu and counting every single flower in the lake.

Answer (score 1):

The flickering light of the lady of the lake is NOT the indicator of solving 100% of the game. The light and pose can be switched everytime, off by dissolving the puzzle or turning off the switch at top of the mountanin peak, and one can only activate it by starting to drive with the angel-like cabin to regularly end the game. I have solved different numbers of puzzles for different states to figure this out.
Me, too, has only the 522 puzzles found.

The 7 clamps stand for the 6 video codes plus the 1 light code to switch on the portal to the hotel, so for the corresponding locations of the pillars with treasure chests on it where the sheets with these code lie within.